# RIP, Grant Imahara

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Unfortunately, this is not a myth to be busted, [Grant Imahara has passed away today at 49 years old](https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/grant-imahara-mythbusters-host-dies-035126793.html) ([reportedly](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/grant-imahara-dead-mythbusters-host-was-49-1303101) from a brain aneurysm).

Grant was best known for his role on the Discovery Channel's Mythbusters, however he got his start  working for Lucasfilm’s THX division and Industrial Light and Magic. His contribution to the science fiction and fantasy community include movies like the three *Star Wars* prequels, *Jurassic Park*, *The Matrix Reloaded*, *The Matrix Revolutions*, *Galaxy Quest* and *Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines*.

Probably coolest of all, he is [one of only three people](https://www.starwars.com/news/don-bies-interview) to operator R2-D2 for the prequels. He was also [inducted into the 501st Legion](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Grant_Imahara).

His co-star and friend Adam Savage has captured what all of us who love Grant's work are feeling.

> I’m at a loss. No words. I’ve been part of two big families with Grant Imahara over the last 22 years. Grant was a truly brilliant engineer, artist and performer, but also just such a generous, easygoing, and gentle PERSON. Working with Grant was so much fun. I’ll miss my friend.
>
> <sub><sup>https://twitter.com/donttrythis/status/1282885559816347648</sup></sub>

Comment: an obvious thing to say, but way too early. a young person, very competent yet modest human. seems like he could have had a very long career.